# VSO Hosted Build Controller: Support for .NET 4.6 & Azure SDK 2.7?

Tags: azure, tfsbuild, azure-devops, azure-sdk-.net, .net-4.6

The [Visual Studio Online Hosted Build Controller](https://www.visualstudio.com/get-started/build/hosted-build-controller-vs#software) does not seem to support .NET 4.6 or the Azure SDK 2.7 yet.

Is there any idea as to when these will be supported?

Comment: We rolled out an image update yesterday that has Azure SDK 2.7 and VS 2015 RTM which includes .NET 4.6

Comment: @ChrisPatterson: Ok great.  The documentation should be updated!  Thanks

Comment: What does an image update mean for those of us new to VSO Builds?  Our build is still failing so do we need to update something on our side? Also in light of the 4.6 RyU bug can we have Azure SDK 2.7 without 4.6?